How can I resolve the "Unresolved compilation problems" related to JsonFactory, JsonParser, and JsonToken in my Java code?
I am getting this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
JsonFactory cannot be resolved to a type
JsonParser cannot be resolved to a type
JsonToken cannot be resolved to a variable

I feel like i might be missing some imports.. i did use these on the file :
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;`

and i added this to build.gradle :
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.14.1'

